# C# TcpClient closes the connection on the Server when sending world information with an exception

Tags: c#, tcp, client

I am trying to send all the tiles (which are referred to as Particles, don't confuse them with client particle effects) in my world (500x350 2d array in my World class) through a NetworkStream hooked up with my Client both on the Server and Clientside.

The code is as follows :

```
public int ServerSendWorldData(NetworkStream networkStream, Point from, Point size, bool reportBytesSent, Networking.Client toClient)
    {
        int bytesOfAcknowledgementSent = 0;
        int totalBytesSent = 0;
        int tilesSentThisAcknowledgement = 0;
        int tilesToSendForThisAcknowledgement = 20;

        for (int x = from.X; x < size.X; x++)
        {
            for (int y = from.Y; y < size.Y; y++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);

                //Handle acknowledgement if needed.
                if (tilesSentThisAcknowledgement >= tilesToSendForThisAcknowledgement)
                {
                    //Wait for Client acknowledgement.
                    bytesOfAcknowledgementSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromByte((byte)Networking.MessageType.ServerSendWorldMapDataWaitAcknowledgement, networkStream);

                    //Handle here.
                    if (networkStream.ReadByte() == (byte)Networking.MessageType.ClientAcknowledgeWorldMapData)
                        tilesSentThisAcknowledgement = 0;
                    else
                        throw new Exception("Client did not acknowledge data!");
                }

                if (world.worldParticles[x, y] != null)
                {
                    //Send Particle Data
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromByte((byte)Networking.MessageType.ServerSendWorldMapDataParticle, networkStream);
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromInt(x, networkStream);
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromInt(y, networkStream);
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromInt(world.worldParticles[x, y].ID, networkStream);
                    //totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromInt(world.worldParticles[x, y].spriteIndex, networkStream);
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromBool(world.worldParticles[x, y].draw, networkStream);
                    totalBytesSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromBool(world.worldParticles[x, y].collisionWithEntities, networkStream);

                    tilesSentThisAcknowledgement++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (reportBytesSent)
        {
            Statistics.Console.WriteLine("Sent " + totalBytesSent + " bytes of World data to Client " + toClient.name + " and " + bytesOfAcknowledgementSent + " bytes of acknowledgement was exchanged!");
        }

        return totalBytesSent;
    }
```

The NetworkingHelp class is basically just networkStream.Write with either a BitConverter converting data such as ints to bytes or an Encoding converting data such as strings to bytes in UTF8.

The code sends a total of 0.76 MB of map data to the Client.

The problem I am having is not present when connecting to the server using localhost / IPAddress.Loopback, but the problem appears when sending data to Clients through the internet - the data is sent extremely slowly (probably due to the file size, I'm unsure though) and without the "Handle Acknowledgement" bit of code ...

```
            //Handle acknowledgement if needed.
            if (tilesSentThisAcknowledgement >= tilesToSendForThisAcknowledgement)
            {
                //Wait for Client acknowledgement.
                bytesOfAcknowledgementSent += Networking.NetworkingHelp.SendMessageFromByte((byte)Networking.MessageType.ServerSendWorldMapDataWaitAcknowledgement, networkStream);

                //Handle here.
                if (networkStream.ReadByte() == (byte)Networking.MessageType.ClientAcknowledgeWorldMapData)
                    tilesSentThisAcknowledgement = 0;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Client did not acknowledge data!");
            }
```

... the Client recieves about 20 world tiles and throws the exception "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", this seems to happen because the Client gets a 1 byte message with byte 0 as its contents.

It seems that the pause created by the "Handle Acknowledgement" code solves this problem, but makes the world data transfer a lot slower.

Help would be much appreciated, and I'm aware my code is kind of messy (open to suggestions on how to improve it, it's my first time sending this much data). Here is the block of code for reading the particular message for the Client.

```
        //WorldParticlesMapDataParticle
        else if (recievedMessage[0] == (byte)Networking.MessageType.ServerSendWorldMapDataParticle)
        {
            //Read the position of the new data.
            recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 4);
            int newParticleX = BitConverter.ToInt32(recievedMessage, 0);
            recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 4);
            int newParticleY = BitConverter.ToInt32(recievedMessage, 0);

            //Read the particle ParticleID.
            recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 4);
            int newParticleID = BitConverter.ToInt32(recievedMessage, 0);

            //Read the particle SpriteID.
            //recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 4);
            //int newSpriteID = BitConverter.ToInt32(recievedMessage, 0);

            //Read the particle draw.
            recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 1);
            bool newParticleDraw = BitConverter.ToBoolean(recievedMessage, 0);

            //Read the particle collision.
            recievedMessageBytes = networkStream.Read(recievedMessage, 0, 1);
            bool newParticleCollision = BitConverter.ToBoolean(recievedMessage, 0);

            //Set particle.
            try
            {
                world.worldParticles[newParticleX, newParticleY] = World.Particle.ParticleManager.particleArray[newParticleID];
                //world.worldParticles[newParticleX, newParticleY].spriteIndex = newSpriteID;
                world.worldParticles[newParticleX, newParticleY].draw = newParticleDraw;
                world.worldParticles[newParticleX, newParticleY].collisionWithEntities = newParticleCollision;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Statistics.Console.WriteLine("Server requested new Particle at " + newParticleX + "," + newParticleY + ", but Client failed to place it due to an exception : " + ex.Message);

                try
                {
                    world.worldParticles[newParticleX, newParticleY] = null;
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ignore the return value from `NetworkStream.Read`. I think you are assuming that it will always read the number of bytes you asked it to read unless there's an error. In fact, the number of bytes you specify is just the *maximum* it will read and it will not read more bytes than are currently available when you call it.

"This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0. **The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter.** If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return zero bytes." - [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx)

You have made the classic mistake of assuming TCP will somehow 'glue together' data just because you sent it in a single call. In fact, TCP has no such mechanism.

Comment: What do you think would be the best way to combat this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Design and implement a protocol on top of TCP that supports messages. Use the low-level write call only to send an entire message. Pass the low-level read call a large maximum byte size and split the data into messages in your own code, then pass only complete messages to your parser/handler. (This will help a lot with your performance problems as well.)

Answer (score 1):

you are sending one particle at a time  try making a big array of what you want to send and send it in one chunk

Answer (score 1):

To complement David Schwartz's answer, you would be wise to read Stephen Cleary's [TCP/IP FAQ](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html), especially the [message framing section](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)